# position elements centered and off-centered in Bootstrap 4 container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 I have a `container-fluid`. I place a logo in the center of the container.

```html
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img src="logo.png">
<div>
```

Now I want to add and additional element which acts as a button.

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">button</a>
```

Vertically the button should be centered.    Its horizontal position should be a fixed amount of pixels to the right of the logo.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```css
.logo-container a.btn {
  left: calc(100% + 50px);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* CSS below is not required, just added it for SO*/
.logo-container {
  min-height: 10rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center logo-container">
  <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/50">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary position-absolute">How to buy</a>
  </div>
<div>
```

In short, you need a wrapper with `position:relative` around the logo and `position:absolute` on the button. I used bootstrap's flex to vertically center the button.

The positioning of the button is done via CSS `left: calc(100% + 50px)`, where `50px` is replaceable with the *"fixed amount of pixels"* you were talking about.

Notice I placed a custom class on the container `.logo-container`. You can obviously replace that with whatever you want. The point is to target that element without affecting other containers/buttons you might have in the project.

If you really don't like custom selectors (which are perfectly fine, btw) for the purpose of this demo, I could have used

```
.container-fluid > .position-relative img + a.btn-secondary.position-absolute {
  left: calc(100% + 50px);
}
```

Way too long but, IMHO, specific enough. Or you could place a unique id on the button to target it.

Comment: I use exactly your code and it is working fine when the button has only "button" as text. However when I use a longer text like "How to buy" the button increases its height, decreases its width and shows the text in 3 lines. What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: It's a weird combination between the parent's `display: flex`, its own `position:absolute` and the spaces in its contents. Can be fixed in several ways: `width: fit-contents;`, `display: inline-table;` or `white-space: nowrap;`. The first one is semantically correct but has the least browser support. The second one is the most semantically incorrect, but probably has the best browser support. The third one will forbid any break lines in its contents regardless of how much text is in it (not good for all cases, but probably good enough for yours).

Comment: @user: and it has ***nothing*** to do with the texts' length. It would behave the same with `b n` as text.

Answer (score 1):

you may use bootsrap class : [`offset-6`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) + [`position-absolute`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/) for the button

```css
/* for demo, to show a ruler */
div {
  padding:1em 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 25%,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%,  transparent 50%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 75%);
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x50/123/cde"  >
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary offset-6 position-absolute">button</a>
</div>
```

---

**edit from comment of @tao**

If you want to set your button at **40px from the logo** you may also use `margin` + `position:absolute` without extra markup:

```css
a.btn {left:50%;margin-left:130px; /* 40px + half the logo's width */}

/* for demo, to show a ruler */
div {
  padding:1em 0;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0 ,transparent 10px ,tomato 10px ,tomato 20px) center}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x50/123/cde"  >
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary  position-absolute">button</a>
</div>
```

---

Last update, in case of an unknown logo's width, it requires extra markup

```css
a.btn {
  margin-left: 40px;
}


/* for demo, to show a ruler */

.d-flex {
  padding: 1em 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0, transparent 10px, tomato 10px, tomato 20px) center
}


}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col p-0"></div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x50/123/cde">
  <div class="col p-0"><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary ">button</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this *"a fixed amount of pixels to the right of the logo"*? Can you apply this solution to make it *"30px to the right of the logo"*?

Comment: @tao , it is only centered in the second half similar to the img . the op did not mention any value. to put aside the logo at 30px. remove offset-6 (equal to margin-left:50%; to margin left:120px , which is half the logo + your thirty px . logo's width is known and the distance  from it is your choice). https://jsfiddle.net/sjex8rq3/

Comment: Logo's width might be known, but it's not guaranteed it's the same across all devices widths. It might make more sense to reduce it on narrow devices, (to accommodate the button, perhaps?) and increase it on bigger screens (to show more detail?). I only find the part where it says the button should be a fixed number of pixels to the right of it.

Comment: @tao i did not see it either. however, if the question was not clear enough, i did miss a part of it. too bad the op did not comment my answer to clarify . I leave it here untill he does ;)

Comment: Besides, the logo's not really a logo (unless OP is selling their logo - as it turns out from the update on the button text). Cheers, happy coding!